# Oracle optimizer stale statistics

Tags: oracle

If a table's statistics are stale, will the optimizer use them?

I am checking the statistics using this query:

```
select
      OWNER,TABLE_NAME,PARTITION_NAME,SUBPARTITION_NAME, NUM_ROWS,LAST_ANALYZED
from dba_TAB_STATISTICS
where STALE_STATS='YES'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > stale stats still get “used”, it’s just that Oracle can detect stale stats and re-collect them as necessary

[Yes](https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/how-does-an-execution-plan-suddenly-change-when-the-statistics-remain-the-same-in-limbo/), they will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Stale statistics will be used by the Optimizer . Hence it is always recommended to refresh the statistics automatically or Periodically.